# LisIterator has add() but doesn't iterate over new added elements

Tags: java, list, listiterator

I am using ListIterator to iterate in the list as I want to add few elements during runtime if certain conditions are met.

But the new elements that are added to the list are never included in the iterator

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] s)
    {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(6);

        ListIterator<Integer> listIterator = list.listIterator();
        while(listIterator.hasNext())
        {
            int i = listIterator.next();
            System.out.println("List Element: " + i + " | List size: " + list.size());
            if(i==1)
            {
                //Adding '3' to list
                listIterator.add(3);
                System.out.println("Added Element: 3");
            }
            if(i==2)
            {
                //Adding '4' to list
                listIterator.add(4);
                System.out.println("Added Element: 4");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the output

```
List Element: 1 | List size: 4
Added Element: 3
List Element: 2 | List size: 5
Added Element: 4
List Element: 5 | List size: 6
List Element: 6 | List size: 6
```

I need to make use of the recently added element in current listIterator but not able to do it.

Is there any other way to iterate over the new elements in the same iteration session?

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc about _where_ `add` adds the element?

Comment: They are not supposed to be included. Why did you *incorrectly* **believe** they should?

Comment: I read the java docs and couldn't capture the explanation. I also posted the code snippet that I tried. I don't think down voting the question was necessary. Also there was no similar question available or explanation available on google or stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `for` loop to iterate and add elements to end of the loop at the same time

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int element = list.get(i);
    if(element == 1){
        System.out.println(element);
        list.add(3);

    }
    else if(element == 2){
        System.out.println(element);
        list.add(4);
    }
    else
        System.out.println(element);
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
1
2
5
6
3
4
[1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

When you call `add` on a `ListIterator<T>`, it places the element immediately before the element that would be returned by `next()`:

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)):

> The new element is inserted before the implicit cursor: a subsequent call to `next()` would be unaffected, and a subsequent call to `previous()` would return the new element.

The logic behind this API design is that the cursor is bidirectional. It has no indication of the direction in which you iterate it, so its designers needed to decide which of the two directions, `next()` or `previous()`, is going to include the newly added element, and so they decided on the `previous()`.

If you would like the cursor to iterate over your newly added element, call `previous()` immediately after the insertion.

Comment: Is there any way to add the new elements at the end of the list during iteration?

Comment: @RahulSinghvi No, there is no method for that. You can add to a separate list, then append it to the main list when you reach the end.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight In his case he can add to the end of his real list and then re-assign his ListIterator pointing to the current location of his original iterator with: `myIter = myList.listIterator(myIter.nextIndex());`